# ssrs-Pass Report parameter to DrillDown

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, ssrs-2008-r2

Im building a report, i make the GROUP BY in the SSRS (not in the DataSET),
means that the group created in the SSRS,

### now, how can i pass the values of the group to the Drill Down?

p.s -  PseudoCOde:
the DataSet (build in sql server 2008):

```
Alter....
Select
     ...Concat(x) MyX
     ,DocumentID
     ,Name
     ,Age
 Group BY DocumentID
```

---

In the SSRS my group is MyX,
MyX - has the values of 'X' that grouped by DocumentID.
now i want to pass the values of MyX to the DrillDown.
how can i do it?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a parameter on the drilldown report to pass the value to. Then on the action that sends you to the drilldown set that parameter's value expression to be:

```
=Fields!MyX.Value
```